# Error: Vector3,Float

Tags: c#, vector, unity-game-engine

I've create a game where a new sprite is 'cloned' every 5 seconds using InvokeRepeating. Once the new sprite is 'cloned' I want it to be cloned at a exact location therefore I used this (C#):

```
newSpike.transform.position = new Vector3 (0.09, 8.27, 0);
```

and I get this error in the console window:
Error CS1503:

> The best overloaded method match for
>   'UnityEngine.Vector3.Vector3(float, float, float)' has some invalid
>   arguments.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Vector3 class works with floats, not doubles.

In C#, you have to append an `f` to your decimals to tell the compiler that you want them to be floats, not doubles.

Try

```
newSpike.transform.position = new Vector3(0.09f, 8.27f, 0f);
```

Comment: Thanks Thomas! Just tried it and it works thanks! 